# Failing to localize WIndows 8 App with Multilingual App Toolkit

Tags: localization, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to localize my Windows 8 App with the Multilingual App Toolkit.
And for that I tried to follow this explanation to the point:

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Build-Multi-language-apps-using-the-Multilingual-App-Toolkit

but it fails with the following Output:

```
1>  Multilingual App Toolkit build started.
1>  Merge of Loc PRI file failed calling makepri.exe: '0x80073B08'
1>  Multilingual App Toolkit build completed with errors.
```

I can't find anything for `0x80073B08`. 
If I remove all xlf language files from the project it compiles, is able to launch and to build a store package.
But as soon as there is any language file included it failes to build with the error above.

Any Ideas?

**EDIT:**

I'm using c# and a single resw file.

Everything works as long as I don't include any xlf files.

There are no duplicate keys (except partly duplicate like "MyButton.Text", "MyButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls]ToolTipService.ToolTip")

**EDIT2:**

Seems like the real problem is the extension format, e.g.:

```
ClearNotesButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls]ToolTipService.ToolTip
```

or

```
AddPageButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name
```

if I use those makepri throws the exception above.
Does this mean I can't set the Tooltip and the Text of a Button via the x:Uid mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

This error code indicates that a (localized) resource add was attempted, but the source resource is not in the PRI file.  Three conditions were recently discovered that can cause this condition for resources.

1. A duplicate resource exists in the resjson file.
   JavaScript Example:
   "Cancel" : "Cancel"
   "cancel" : "Cancel"  <-- Duplicate resource
2. A resource ID conflicts with a different resource with the same base path information.
    
   JavaScript Example:
   "About"       : "About title"
   "About/OKBtn" : "OK".  <-- Resource path is the same as a previous resource's ID

   XAML Example:
   MyButton : "Button without property"
   MyButton.Content : "Hallo Welt" <-- Becomes MyButton/Content, which conflicts with MyButton ID
3. A resource ID contains the same name as the resource file.
   Common Example:
   Filename: Resources.resjson
   "Dialog/Resources/Title" : "Welcome"

Please look for these conflicts as they are know to cause this error message.  You could also see this error on the preview version.  Please ensure that you are running the released version of the toolkit - it is v1.0.1114.0.

Comment: ok I looked into it, but: 1. no duplicate key (at least complete keys, there are some of the form "myKey.Text" and "myKey.ToolTip") 2. I have only one Resources.resw file 3. not the case

Comment: @Cameron I just saw your edit in the suggested edit queue, it looks like you've ended up with two accounts somehow. For your own sanity, you may want to see [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Comment: so how would one for example localize a TextBlock with a Text and a Tooltip?

since you can't use "MyTextBlock.Text" and "MyTextBlock.Tooltip" at the same time...

it basically breaks the x:Uid based approach of localizing, doesn't it?



So I would have to call {x:Static ...} or some Markupextension like {l:Translate ...} and give everything a unique key, or is there a better way?

Comment: hm or is the real problem the extended property format?

e.g.: ClearNotesButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls]ToolTipService.ToolTip

Answer (score 2):

A new version of the Multilingual App Toolkit has been released that will help identify when this issue happens so you can easily adjust the resources.  All three known issues are resolved with this release.  The version is v1.1.1075.0 as displayed in the VS IDE Extensions and Updates dialog.

Comment: the update does not solve the problem with this syntax: "ClearNotesButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls]ToolTipService.ToolTip"

Comment: I just tried with a simple app that has a TextBlock and Button on the page - both with ToolTips.  Here is how I defined them in the ResX file.

LocTitle.Text, 
LocTitle.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls]ToolTipService.ToolTip, 
LocClickMe.Content, 
LocClickMe.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls]ToolTipService.ToolTip  

Can you try with a similar app to see if this work for you?